# How to evaluate the limit $\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\sin^{-1}{x}}{x}$ without using L Hospital

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

I need to evaluate this limit without using L Hospital. This is what I have done so far:

Let's begin with the assumption $x = \sin{t}$

Then as $x\to0$, $t\to0$

Now substituting $\sin{t}$ in place of $x$ in the limit

$$
\begin{align*}
    \lim_{x\to0} \frac{\sin^{-1}{x}}{x} &= \lim_{t\to0} \frac{\sin^{-1}{\sin{t}}}{\sin{t}} \\
    &= \lim_{t\to0} \frac{t}{\sin{t}} \\
    &= \frac{1}{\lim_{t\to0} \frac{\sin{t}}{t}} \\
    &= \frac{1}{1} = 1
\end{align*}
$$

What I am concerned about is that by the assumption $x=\sin{t}$, $x$ is being limited to the interval $[-1,1]$. But as we are concerned about the limit when $x\to0$, I should not worry about the limitation? Besides the domain of $\sin^{-1}{x}$ is $[-1,1]$.

So, are there any errors in the above approach?

Thanks

Comment: Seems OK, but how do you calculate the other limit without L'hospital ? Do you assume this limit is already known ?

Comment: @Peter Yes assume that the other limits are already known, namely $\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\sin{x}}{x} = 1$

Comment: @Peter, one even should not calculate the second limit with L'hospital, because how one can differentiate sine function without knowing that limit?

Comment: @DominikKutek Yes one should never do that. Thanks for adding that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is correct. The only thing I would do differently is start with what's known to be true, i.e. the limit
$$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{t}{\sin t}=1 $$
then substitute $t=\sin^{-1}x\to 0$ as $x\to 0$ to arrive at the limit that needs to be shown. As for your question about limiting the values of $x$, since we're talking about a limit as $x\to 0$, you may assume that $x\in(-\varepsilon,0)\cup(0,\varepsilon)$ for an arbitrary $\varepsilon>0$. This simply follows from the definition of a limit.

Comment: It is very, very common to start with what one wants to show and work towards something one knows. Mostly because one often doesn't know ahead of time exactly which already-known thing will be useful. Taking care that the logic works the direction it should is, of course, still important.

Answer (score 0):

We need to use here the **Taylor series**:
$$
\bbox[lightgreen]
{
\arcsin(x)=\left(x+\frac{x^{3}}{6}+\frac{3x^{5}}{40}+....\right)
},\tag{1}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\lim_{x\to{0}}\frac{\arcsin{x}}{x}=\lim_{x\to{0}}\frac{\left(x+\frac{x^{3}}{6}+\frac{3x^{5}}{40}+....\right)}{x}=
\\
=\lim_{x\to{0}}\frac{x\left(1+\frac{x^{2}}{6}+\frac{3x^{4}}{40}+....\right)}{x}=\lim_{x\to{0}}\left(1+\frac{x^{2}}{6}+\frac{3x^{4}}{40}+....\right)=1.
$$
Here is the result:
$$
\bbox[lightblue]
{
\lim_{x\to{0}}\frac{\arcsin{x}}{x}=1
}.
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But we haven't studied Taylor Series Expansion yet. Are there any errors in my approach??

Comment: @Prabodh, Respected Mr. Prabodh, you have used the substitution $x=\sin(t)$ and obtained after additional transformations the standard limit $\lim_{x\to{0}}\frac{\sin{x}}{x}=1$. In your proof any mistakes are absent.

Comment: Thank you for your remarks. Have a great day